# Changing the font of cross-references in a Word 2010 document

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, cross-reference

I have a very large word document (250 pages) with lots of cross-references inserted in the text (mainly tables and figures as Figure 2.1 or Table 4.3 etc).

The main text of the document is set to Calibri 12. The font of the cross-references is coming up as Arial 12.

I have too many cross-references to change them all manually. I have searched on Google to see if I can find style-set for the 'cross-referencing text' so I can change it to Calibri 12, but I am not having any luck.

I need this done fairly soon for a thesis, I hope some can help me with this. I am using Word 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Replace functionality (Home tab on the ribbon, then "Replace" on the Editing section.). You can specify that you only want to search a particular style (I believe cross references are considered "captions"). This will limit the search to only the style you want to change.

[image: Word Style Replacement]

1. With your cursor in the "Find what" box, click the `Format` button and select Style, then Caption.
2. To limit to only captions with the unwanted font, click `Format` again, select Font, then Arial 12.
3. Click in the "Replace with" box, click `Format` again, and select Font, then Calibri 12.

This should replace all instances of Arial 12 in captions with Calibri 12. You may need to experiment with other styles (aside from 'caption') in case your cross-references are being classified as something else.